# condition and regex phonegap

Tags: javascript, regex, cordova

I can't understand why my condition didn't works

```
$('#resPage').live('pageshow', function(event) {

    application.previousButton();

    //get pdf
    var text = '';
    var value;
    var get = application.readGet();
    switch(get['id']){
        case '1':
            var patt = /annales/g;
            var cutLen = 20;
            break;
         case '2':
             var patt = /copies/g;
             var cutLen = 19;
             break;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url:application.api+'/ressources',
        success:function(data){
            text = "<ul data-role='listview' data-inset='true' >"
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            for(elem in data.files){
            console.log(elem)
            console.log(patt.test(data.files[elem]));
            if(patt.test(data.files[elem])){
                console.log('add');
                value = data.files[elem].substr(1);
                text += application.textRelLink(value,cutLen);
            }
        }   
        text +="</ul>" 
        $('#resPage .content').html(text);
        $('#resPage .content ul').listview();
        }
    })
});
```

In my log I have:

```
03-02 11:03:14.722: D/CordovaLog(23226): 0
03-02 11:03:14.722: D/CordovaLog(23226): false
03-02 11:03:14.722: D/CordovaLog(23226): 1
03-02 11:03:14.722: D/CordovaLog(23226): false
03-02 11:03:14.722: D/CordovaLog(23226): 2
03-02 11:03:14.722: D/CordovaLog(23226): true
03-02 11:03:14.722: D/CordovaLog(23226): 3
03-02 11:03:14.722: D/CordovaLog(23226): true
03-02 11:03:14.730: D/CordovaLog(23226): 4
03-02 11:03:14.730: D/CordovaLog(23226): true
03-02 11:03:14.730: D/CordovaLog(23226): 5
03-02 11:03:14.745: D/CordovaLog(23226): false
03-02 11:03:14.745: D/CordovaLog(23226): 6
03-02 11:03:14.745: D/CordovaLog(23226): false
```

But I never have add when true

Thanks for the help

Edit:

Data value before parsing

```
03-02 11:25:05.253: D/CordovaLog(23611): {"files":[".\/thumbs\/pdf\/methodo\/sdsdfsd_sdf.pdf",".\/thumbs\/pdf\/methodo\/test!!.pdf",".\/thumbs\/pdf\/annales\/ddfgdfg.pdf",".\/thumbs\/pdf\/annales\/big.pdf",".\/thumbs\/pdf\/annales\/test.pdf",".\/thumbs\/pdf\/copies\/test.pdf",".\/thumbs\/pdf\/poly\/gdfhf.pdf"],"dirs":[".\/thumbs\/pdf\/poly\/",".\/thumbs\/pdf\/copies\/",".\/thumbs\/pdf\/annales\/",".\/thumbs\/pdf\/methodo\/"]}
```

Comment: may I see the return value of `data` in your success block of ajax?

Comment: I added the data before parsing

Comment: I don't think your condition here `patt.test(data.files[elem])` went to true. That's the reason you never had `add` printed at your log.

Comment: ok, but I have true in my log and this is the same condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the `lastIndex` property of the regular expression before re-testing

```
console.log(patt.test(data.files[elem]));
patt.lastIndex = 0;
if(patt.test(data.files[elem])){
```

Alternatively, if you get rid of the unnecessary `g` flag from the regex, there is no need to reset `lastIndex`.

When a regex is used with the `g` flag it keeps track of where the last match was found so that the next test starts searching from that point, the `lastIndex`.

See [Why RegExp with global flag in Javascript give wrong results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-regexp-with-global-flag-in-javascript-give-wrong-results).